# Yii2 class not found on Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii2

I have a model class that refer to a table of my database:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Pricing extends ActiveRecord
{

}
```

I try to use a simple php function on a separate php file (called pricing.php and placed in ../web):

```
<?php

use app\models\Pricing;

$pricings = Pricing::find()->all();
echo $pricings[0]->weekPrice;

?>
```

This php file aim to be called on a javascript event with ajax:

```
function actualizePrice() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'pricing.php',
        success: function (response) {
            actualize()
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('error');
        },
    });
    return false;
}
```

But I get a `Uncaught Error: Class 'app\models\Pricing' not found`, any idea what is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you shoudn't be creating any new php files in files files in `/web`

you need to [create an action](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html#actions) somewhere inside one of your yii controllers (or a make a new one) and point your js to that action (something like `/site/pricing` or `index.php?r=site%2Fpricing`)

Comment: I created an Action inside `SiteController`: `public function actionPricing(){
      $pricings = Pricing::find()->all();
      return $pricings[0]->weekPrice;
    }` and then try to redirect the ajax url to it with `url:'/site/pricing'` but all I get is a 404 error.

Comment: @MHogge keep in mind that the path `/site/pricing` is dependent on config, you would ideally you shuld create urls with `Url::to(['site/index'])` if you post your `urlManager` config in your question i can update my aswer

Comment: I do not have any urlManager (I just have a commented out urlManager inside web.php but since it is commented...), is it possible? (I'm a very beginner with web development and even more with Yii2, sorry)

Comment: @MHogge yeah, you're using the default configuration. Use `index.php?r=site%2Fpricing` as url

Comment: Since I'm using the default configuration, what's wrong with what I've did?

Comment: change the ajax url to the format i've mentioned. i updated the answer